# How do I get the camber back to 0, with no adjustments

Tags: struts

Just put new struts and control arms on a 2010 but, and the wheels have negative camber now. They don't have any adjustments on the new struts, how do I get the wheels back straight.

Comment: Make ,model and year of manufacture, front or rear, goes along way in getting responses.

Comment: Double what @mikes said.

Comment: post what @mikes said, but it will be best for you to visit a wheel alignment store, getting 0 from household method is nearly impossible

Comment: If the camber is so obvious - have you fitted the correct parts?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I have seen on many cars that the bottom two bolts and nuts on the spindle onto to the strut will allow a very small amount of movement for back and forth (before you tighten them all the way). Make sure you put them exactly where they were before, this can affect the camber.